# correct usage of preposition 'on' and 'by'

Tags: grammar, prepositions

which is the correct sentence?

Mr. Parkash leads a very busy life so he goes everywhere by a scooter.

Mr. Parkash leads a very busy life so he goes everywhere on a scooter.

Comment: Both are correct. "By" describes the means/method; "On" describes the place/location - he is on a scooter.

Comment: The first is unidiomatic; 'by scooter' rather than 'by a scooter' is used, in line with 'by bus', 'by train', 'by plane' etc. It is the more common usage; 'on a scooter' is informal, almost chatty.

Comment: As Edwin says, you wouldn't go anywhere by a scooter, just like you wouldn't go anywhere by a car or by a foot.

Comment: I overlooked the first "a"...

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the article "a" from your sentence using "by", you have two idiomatic ways of essentially saying the same thing:

> Mr. Parkash leads a very busy life so he goes everywhere *by scooter*.
>
> Mr. Parkash leads a very busy life so he goes everywhere *on a scooter*.

Both are correct. *By car, by train, by plane, by boat etc* are all idiomatic ways of describing the mode or transport. You can also say *by air, by sea, by road etc* which does not specify the type of vehicle but broadly describes the mode of travel.

When you specificy the vehicle, you have to use the appropriate preposition. For example, you would say *in* a car, but *on* a bike or scooter (because you sit atop them).